# Is there a way to change DATE format on?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to store some date in my SQL database, the problem is that the default storage is

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

And I need

```
DD-MM-YYYY
```

My only solution was to store date as Varchars (10) and it's working pretty well, but now I can't order my queries by DATE, and I need to order them from the oldest to the newest...

Comment: why dont u store in timestamp and then change accordingly ??? u can check the listing at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

Comment: What you need for *display* purposes shouldn't change how you *store* data. If its datetime data, store it in an appropriate datetime type. The database knows how to sort datetime values appropriately. Then, when you want to show the values to someone, do your formatting *there*. The biggest source of datetime errors with databases is when people try to use strings to represent them.

Comment: Upvoted @swapnesh, but would like to clarify this a bit. See, you don't store dates in MySQL: you store _facts_. And a fact that some event happened in a particular point in time doesn't change whenever you want this point in time stored as 'YYYY-MM-DD', or 'DD-MM-YYYY', or even 'MM-DD-YYYY', god bless those who invented this format. It's all details of how this fact should be represented, and 99 times of 100 you shouldn't store the representation-related details (not facts!) in your DB.

Comment: Ok for the display part, But then my user isn't going to input YYYY-MM-DD, So how can i store a DD-MM-YYYY date, converting it to a YYYY-MM-DD format ?

Comment: Yes. On input, convert to a datetime value (rather than a string) as early as possible. On output, leave conversion from datetimes into strings as late as possible. It's usually best to do both of these things in whatever application language you're using to write your UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to change the default date format for a MySQL date or either of its variants - DATETIME, TIMESTAMP and DATE.

Quoting the manual:

```
Although MySQL tries to interpret values in several formats, dates always must be given 
 in year-month-day order (for example, '98-09-04'), rather than in the month-day-year or 
day-month-year orders commonly used elsewhere 
(for example, '09-04-98', '04-09-98').
```

Consider the native [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function as rightly suggested by @Micheal in his post.

Answer (score 4):

Use the native [`DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%d-%e-%Y') FROM your_table;
```